# Can I have multiple iOS devices connected to a mac running appium?

Tags: ios, selenium, webdriver, appium

I'm trying to add iOS devices to a Selenium Grid using appium. It seems a bit extravagant to have one mac per device, but that's what everything I've read so far implies.

Is it possible to run two appium servers on the same machine? Or have one appium instance that can switch between multiple devices based on the capabilities passed in? The tests don't have to run at the same time - I think Instruments puts a stop to that idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation imposed by Apple's UIAutomation framework and Instruments.app. There are several ways that we are considering to get around it, but at the moment we have not implemented any of them.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to run parallel tests on real iOS devices connected to one Mac machine.
For this you have to run appium from command line on different ports, and specify different temp directories for each appium instances.